# Rendering issue with different computers

Tags: c++, opengl

So i am making a short of tower defense game. I shared a build with them so i can check if everything performs as it should on another host.

And what actually happens is that while everything renders perfectly on my side (both on my mac/xcode + windows/visual studio 2012), on my friend's side it seems like the geometry is messed up. Each object on my screen is represented by a VBO which i use every time to render to different locations. But it seems like my VBOs have all the geometry imported from all models. (Hence the Tower with the tree on the side.)

Here's the result:

[image](My computer)[image](My friend's computer)

As by now i've managed to debug this issue up to a certain point. I can tell it's not the way i'm importing my models because i'm creating a debug.txt file with all the vectors before i send them to gpu as VBOs and on both computers they output the same values. So i their vectors are not getting messed up by memory issues or anything like that. So i am thinking maybe it is the way i am setting up or rendering my VBOs

What strikes me the most though is why things work on my computer while they are not on my friends computer. One difference i know for sure is that my computer is a developer station(whatever this means) while my friend's computer is not.

This is my VBO loading function and my VBO drawing function:
I use glfw to create my window and context and include glew headers to enable some of the newer opengl functions.

```
void               G4::Renderer::LoadObject(
                                           G4::TILE_TYPES   aType,
                                           std::vector<float> &v_data,
                                           std::vector<float> &n_data,
                                           std::vector<float> &t_data,
                                           float scale,
                                           bool has_texture,
                                           unsigned int texture_id
                                           )
{

    unsigned int vertices_id, vertices_size, normals_id, texturecoordinates_id;

    vertices_size   = static_cast<unsigned int>(v_data.size());

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertices_id);
    glGenBuffers(1, &normals_id);

    //::->Vertex array buffer upload.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*v_data.size(), &v_data.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //::->Normal Array buffer upload.
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normals_id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*n_data.size(), &n_data.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);



    if (has_texture)
    {
        glGenBuffers(1, &texturecoordinates_id);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texturecoordinates_id);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*t_data.size(), &(t_data[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }


    this->vbos[aType].Update(vertices_id, vertices_size, normals_id, texture_id, texturecoordinates_id, scale, has_texture);



}
```

Draw code:

```
void G4::Renderer::DrawUnit(G4::VBO aVBO, bool drawWithColor, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    bool model_has_texture = aVBO.HasTexture();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    if (model_has_texture && !drawWithColor)  {
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    if (drawWithColor)
    {
        glColor4f(r, g, b, a);
    }

    glScalef(aVBO.GetScaleValue(), aVBO.GetScaleValue(), aVBO.GetScaleValue());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, aVBO.GetVerticesID());
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, aVBO.GetNormalsID());
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    if (model_has_texture && !drawWithColor)
    {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, aVBO.GetTextureID());
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, aVBO.GetTextureCoordsID());
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, aVBO.GetVerticesSize());

    if (model_has_texture && !drawWithColor)  {
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    } 

    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

}
```

I'm out of ideas i hope someone can direct me on how to debug this any further.

Comment: Those artifacts look more like an rasterization issue, than a geometry issue. Since you're rendering actual geometry such artifacts as they are visible hint toward a hardware problem. Ask your friend if he's overclocking his GPU and/or its memory. Also try out what happens after an driver update or after replacement with another GPU of the same type.

Comment: i refuse to believe it's hardware related. Plus i tried a computer of another friend of mine and he is experiencing the same results as my other friend does. Also what you call artifacts as i mention in the question i managed to identify them as geometry from (probably) every other model im importing. They seem to merge into one

Comment: You could always just throw it all out and start over using the [modern openGL API](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-1:-The-Graphics-Pipeline.html) (semi-serious)

Comment: One thing that sticks out like a sore thumb is that you are calling glScalef (...) unconditionally. In the old deprecated portion of the OpenGL API, glScale (...) multiplies the current matrix, so unless your scale is always 1.0 successive calls to this DrawUnit (...) function are going to continue messing up your matrix. You very likely want to load your matrices fresh each time before you do this, or push and pop the existing matrices onto and off the stack.

Comment: @Andon It is variable and that's a good observation but im calling glPushMatrix before every DrawUnit call and glPopMatrix right after it. Im using deprecated functions for now because i intend to focus on complete shader implementation later. I already am but lightweight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenGL spec. does not specify the exact behaviour that should occur when you issue a draw call with more vertices than your buffer stores. The reason this may work correctly on one machine and not on another comes down to implementation. Each vendor is free to do whatever they want if this situation occurs, so the render artifacts might show up on AMD hardware but not at all on nVIDIA or Intel. Making matters worse, there is actually no error state generated by a call to `glDrawArrays (...)` when it is asked to draw too many vertices. You definitely need to test your software on hardware sourced from multiple vendors to catch these sorts of errors; who manufactures the GPU in your computer, and the driver version, is just as important as the operating system and compiler.

Nevertheless there are ways to catch these silly mistakes. gDEBugger is one, and there is also a new OpenGL extension I will discuss below. I prefer to use the new extension because in my experience, in addition to deprecated API calls and errors (which gDEBugger can be configured to monitor), the extension can also warn you for using inefficiently aligned data structures and various other portability and performance issues.

I wanted to add some code I use to use OpenGL Debug Output in my software, since this is an example of an errant behaviour that does not actually generate an error that you can catch with `glGetError (...)`. Sometimes, you can catch these mistakes with Debug Output (though, I just tested it and this is not one of those situations). You will need an OpenGL Debug Context for this to work (the process of setting this up is highly platform dependent), but it is a context flag just like forward/backward compatible and core (glfw should make this easy for you).

Automatic breakpoint macro for x86 platforms

```
// Breakpoints that should ALWAYS trigger (EVEN IN RELEASE BUILDS) [x86]!
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# define eTB_CriticalBreakPoint() if (IsDebuggerPresent ()) __debugbreak ();
#else
# define eTB_CriticalBreakPoint() asm (" int $3");
#endif
```

Enable OpenGL Debug Output (requires a Debug Context and a relatively recent driver, OpenGL 4.x era)

```
// SUPER VERBOSE DEBUGGING!
if (glDebugMessageControlARB != NULL) {
  glEnable                  (GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS_ARB);
  glDebugMessageControlARB  (GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, NULL, GL_TRUE);
  glDebugMessageCallbackARB ((GLDEBUGPROCARB)ETB_GL_ERROR_CALLBACK, NULL);
}
```

Some important utility functions to replace enumerant values with more meaningful text

```
const char*
ETB_GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_STR (GLenum source)
{
  static const char* sources [] = {
    "API",   "Window System", "Shader Compiler", "Third Party", "Application",
    "Other", "Unknown"
  };

  int str_idx =
    min ( source - GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API,
            sizeof (sources) / sizeof (const char *) );

  return sources [str_idx];
}

const char*
ETB_GL_DEBUG_TYPE_STR (GLenum type)
{
  static const char* types [] = {
    "Error",       "Deprecated Behavior", "Undefined Behavior", "Portability",
    "Performance", "Other",               "Unknown"
  };

  int str_idx =
    min ( type - GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR,
            sizeof (types) / sizeof (const char *) );

  return types [str_idx];
}

const char*
ETB_GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_STR (GLenum severity)
{
  static const char* severities [] = {
    "High", "Medium", "Low", "Unknown"
  };

  int str_idx =
    min ( severity - GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH,
            sizeof (severities) / sizeof (const char *) );

  return severities [str_idx];
}

DWORD
ETB_GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_COLOR (GLenum severity)
{
  static DWORD severities [] = {
    0xff0000ff, // High (Red)
    0xff00ffff, // Med  (Yellow)
    0xff00ff00, // Low  (Green)
    0xffffffff  // ???  (White)
  };

  int col_idx =
    min ( severity - GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH,
            sizeof (severities) / sizeof (DWORD) );

  return severities [col_idx];
}
```

My **Debug Output Callback** (somewhat messy, because it prints each field in a different color in my software)

```
void
ETB_GL_ERROR_CALLBACK (GLenum        source,
                       GLenum        type,
                       GLuint        id,
                       GLenum        severity,
                       GLsizei       length,
                       const GLchar* message,
                       GLvoid*       userParam)
{
  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xff00ffff, "OpenGL Error:\n");
  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xff808080, "=============\n");

  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xff6060ff, " Object ID: ");
  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xff0080ff, "%d\n", id);

  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xff60ff60, " Severity:  ");
  eTB_ColorPrintf ( ETB_GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_COLOR   (severity),
                      "%s\n",
                        ETB_GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_STR (severity) );

  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xffddff80, " Type:      ");
  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xffccaa80, "%s\n", ETB_GL_DEBUG_TYPE_STR     (type));

  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xffddff80, " Source:    ");
  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xffccaa80, "%s\n", ETB_GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_STR   (source));

  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xffff6060, " Message:   ");
  eTB_ColorPrintf (0xff0000ff, "%s\n\n", message);

  // Force the console to flush its contents before executing a breakpoint
  eTB_FlushConsole ();

  // Trigger a breakpoint in gDEBugger...
  glFinish ();

  // Trigger a breakpoint in traditional debuggers...
  eTB_CriticalBreakPoint ();
}
```

Since I could not actually get your situation to trigger a debug output event, I figured I would at least show an example of an event I was able to trigger. This is not an error that you can catch with `glGetError (...)`, or an error at all for that matter. But it is certainly a draw call issue that you might be completely oblivious to for the duration of your project without using this extension :)

```
OpenGL Error:
=============
 Object ID: 102
 Severity:  Medium
 Type:      Performance
 Source:    API
 Message:   glDrawElements uses element index type 'GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE' that is not optimal for the current hardware configuration; consider using 'GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT' instead.
```

Comment: This is more than i could ever ask for, thank you so much. And all that additional info on the extra debugging tools upon the opengl context is very, very interesting of which i was not aware off. I thought glGetError was your only friend on this.

Answer (score 4):

After further debugging sessions with my friends and much tryouts i managed to find the problem. This took me two solid days to figure out and really it was just a silly mistake.

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, aVBO.GetVerticesSize());
```

The above code does not get the vertices size (as points) but as a total number of floats stored there. So everything is multiplied by 3. Adding a /3 solved it.

So i assume since the total points where multiplied by 3 times the vbo "stole" data from other vbos stored on the gpu. (Hence the tree model stack to my tower).

What i can't figure out yet though, and would like an answer on that, is why on my computer everything rendered fine but not on other computers. As i state in my original question a hint would be that my computer is actually a developer station while my friend's not.
Anyone who is kind enough to explain why this effect doesn't reproduce on me i will gladly accept his answer as a solution to my problem.

Thank you

Comment: I was just about to ask that :) I noticed you passed vertices_size to Update (...), which was really the number of float components in your array of vertex positions. In any case, if you try to draw more vertices than your array stores it kind of invokes undefined behaviour. Which, as we all know, is where a lot of vendor-specific behaviour arises. If you have a newer OpenGL driver implementation, the OpenGL Debug Output extension will usually tell you when you overrun an array on a draw call. A lot of things that are errant, but that do not generate errors through glGetError show up that way.

Comment: Spot on! Silly of me though.. Any chance you can aid solving the 2nd part of the mystery here?

Comment: @Bisder: You almost certainly are using different video cards, or different driver versions.  One driver might refuse to draw the extra vertices, others might draw whatever is next in memory but store things in different orders in memory.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman You should add this as an answer you deserve to get accepted.
BenVoigt: Thank you also upvoted