# glTexStorage2D returns out of memory

Tags: opengl

I am using the following code to upload my textures on the GPU in a loop before starting to render but I get some 'random' out of memory error returned by glTexStorage2D.  I mean that sometimes a smaller texture return out of memory but the next one, a bigger one returns ok.  I checked with GPU-Z and only 180MB of the video card memory (1GB) is used.  I also used Gdebugger and there is not much memory used (VBOs, Front/Back buffers, Textures, Shaders).  The textures are between 32x32 to 2048x2048.

```
glGenTextures(1, &TextureID);
showGlError();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureID); 
showGlError();

Nof_MipMap = 2; 

glTexStorage2D(
   GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
   Nof_MipMap, 
   GL_RGBA8, 
   Image_Width, Image_Height);
glError = showGlError();

glTexSubImage2D(
   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
   0,
   0, 0,
   Image_Width, Image_Height,
   GL_RGB,
   GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5_REV,
   Image_Address);
glError = showGlError();

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);  //Generate num_mipmaps number of mipmaps here.
glError = showGlError();

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
showGlError();
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
showGlError();
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
showGlError();
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
showGlError();
```

Comment: Sounds like [memory fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computing%29).  Can you load all the large textures first?

Comment: You may not have read my paragraph completely.  I mentioned that only 180MB out of 1GB was used.  So this would mean that 820MB (80%) would be lost by memory fragmentation.

Comment: It's not impossible, so genpfault's recommendation still holds.

Comment: So you think it's possible that there would be no room for a 128x128 texture but there would be room for 256x256 because of memory fragmentation?  I honestly cannot understand how.  I ran a test just after reboot and got a similar result.  My understanding is that fragmentation would occur when textures get deallocated but the problem occurs at the beginning of the program where only allocation is performed.  Unless the driver has a minimum allocation size that is very big and I allocate a large amount of small textures perhaps?  Like the cluster size of 32k on disk that makes 1k file take 32k

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that GPU-Z measures resident VRAM size. There are a number of locations texture data can exist, in your processes user-mode address space, in its kernel-mode address space (in older versions of Windows with kernel-mode graphics API drivers), in the space allocated by your BIOS / EFI for AGP / PCIe GART (system shared graphics memory), or in VRAM.

Out Of Memory is such a vague error that it is almost meaningless by itself given the complexity of today's memory management schemes. Java Virtual Machines (not that it applies here, but you get the idea) introduce yet another artificial memory limitation, with a 256 MiB heap by default. If your GPU / driver are relatively new, I would look into using `GL_ARB_debug_output` to get a more detailed explanation of what is going on.

I have an example of how to use this extension in an answer I wrote a few months ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064988/rendering-issue-with-different-computers/18067245#18067245).